# Query multi tables' columns with join in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Description:**

I have two tables, `Shop_Employee` and `Shop_Employee_Type`. I wanna display `typeName` directly when show the employee detail information, but I don't want to config the relationship(`OneToMany` or `ManyToOne`) between this two entity.
 Because this will load all `Shop_Employee_Type` column's value, but these values are useless for me, I just need `typeName` of `Shop_Employee_Type`.
Below is my code, but it doesn't work.

**ShopEmployeeType:**

```
@Entity
@Data
//@DynamicUpdate
public class ShopEmployeeType {
    @Id
    private String typeId;
    private String shopId;
    private String typeName;
    private Integer typeStatus;
    private String typeDescription;
}
```

**Shop_Employee:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ShopEmployee {

    @Id
    private  String employeeId;
    private String shopId;
    private String typeId;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String phone;
    private Integer status;
    private String idcardNumber;
    private String image;
    //@Transient
    private String typeName;

    public ShopEmployee() {
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Query(value = "select u.*,t.type_name from shop_employee u inner join shop_employee_type t on u.type_id=t.type_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShopEmployee> findAllData();
```

This could show `typeName` as I wished, but there is an error appears when I save a new entity Shop_Employee; If I add a `@Transient` for 'typeName', It could save successfully, but the value of 'typeName' is null when I query entity `Shop_Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should return two Objects `Shop_Employee` and a `String`, so the return results should not be `List<ShopEmployee>` it should be :

```
@Query(value = "select u.*, t.type_name from shop_employee ...", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findAllData();
```

Then you can get the `ShopEmployee` using :

```
List<Object[]> list = findAllData();
for(Object[] obj : list){
   ShopEmployee shopEmployee = (ShopEmployee) obj[0];
   String type_name = (String) obj[1];
}
```

So, in `ShopEmployee` entity you don't need to use :

```
//@Transient
//private String typeName;
```